# Sort a 2D array by a portion of a string

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to sort an array with data that looks like this

```
[
[123456789 - person@company.com - 02/15/2024 9:00 PM],
[9876543210 - person2@company.com - 02/13/2024 6:00 AM],
[1234506789 - person3@company.com - 02/15/2024 7:00 AM]
]
```

The intended result should look like this

```
[
[9876543210 - person2@company.com - 02/13/2024 6:00 AM],
[1234506789 - person3@company.com - 02/15/2024 7:00 AM],
[123456789 - person@company.com - 02/15/2024 9:00 PM]
]
```

So what I'm trying to do is sort by date, but that date is part of a string that is concatenated like you see above. I'm familiar with splicing and looking for a character position so I thought maybe I can do a search for the last `-` and sort based off of that but I'm lost on how I would go about doing that in an array when sorting. I don't even know where to begin tbh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Suggestion:

Searching for the last `-` is a valid approach. You can then slice the string then parse the sliced section as a date. You can then use the `sort` method to sort the array based on the date.

Check this code snippet for reference:

```js
  var testArray = [
    ['123456789 - person@company.com - 02/15/2024 9:00 PM'],
    ['9876543210 - person2@company.com - 02/13/2024 6:00 AM'],
    ['1234506789 - person3@company.com - 02/15/2024 7:00 AM']
  ]

  
  testArray.sort((a,b) => Date.parse(a[0].slice(a[0].lastIndexOf('-'))) - Date.parse(b[0].slice(b[0].lastIndexOf('-'))))

  console.log(testArray)
```

### References:

- [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)
- [lastIndexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf)
- [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

Comment: This is amazing. It was fast and it worked great! Honestly, I thought I was going to have to split it into it's own array and then match the indexes after sort and then create a new array based off of it. This is definitely not how I thought it would work. Learn something new every day. Love this community. Thanks!